# How to output list of functions for iOS release binary

Tags: ios

We are porting some (mostly written in C++) game to iOS, and we recently introduced a useful macro into C++ code which (as a side effect) generates some redundant code. This code is sort of

```
void f(D1 *d1) {
    f(static_cast<B *>(d1));
}

void f(D2 *d2) {
    f(static_cast<B *>(d2));
}

...

void f(DN *dN) {
    f(static_cast<B *>(dN));
}
```

We want to make sure that global optimization step (or whatever you call it) for release build strips away these redundant functions (make them inlined).

What I have is .ipa and .dsym files. So what tool would you suggest to analyze code binary (i.e. to output list of functions in some format) and ... what is code binary in this case? Something inside .ipa?

Comment: Uh, why don't you just use `inline`?

Comment: Because these functions may be called from other compilation units (source files). Maybe "inline" is wrong word here.

Comment: would there by a problem to put them into headers and actually inline them?

Comment: yes. actually, these functions appear as a side-effect of some macro, and they are spread all over source files. I put them next to each other only for illustration. my question is about tools for profiling executable binaries.